# How can I share NTFS drive between Ubuntu PC

Tags: networking, samba, ntfs, file-sharing

I am just installing Ubuntu 12.04 in my office in two PC. Every PC have some NTFS formated drive. So I want to share them between these two PCs. Please help me regent if possible.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to download samba package from command line by this command apt-get install samba then you can go cd /etc/samba.smb.conf an write the following line [sharefile]
path = /home/name of folder
browseable = yes
public = yes
writable = yes
read only = no 
guest ok = yes 
force create mask = 0755
force directory mask = 0755

save the file and then restar snmbd and nambd file you can get the sharing file or right click on file sharing file go into share tab and do the GUI and ...... 
hope it can be useful for you

Answer (score 0):

If you have a GUI installed on your Ubuntu PC, just `richt-click` the to be shared folder and  select  `Sharing Options`. Check the "Share this folder" check-box.

If you have not installed the sharing service, a popup will ask you to do so. That should be all there is ;)

If you run into troubles let us know!